# Devise - Perform actions after authentication, but before redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, devise, haml

I'm trying to perform actions after the creation of a session and before the redirect.   The user subscribes to a lesson, and after they've picked a lesson to sign up for, I'd like to provide the option to just sign in, and use their existing card on file to finalize the purchase without making them go through the process again (it's very clearly stated that this will happen on the form).

I'm currently overriding the default actions for Devise, like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions'}
end
```

And using this controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super
    my_service = MyService.new
    my_service.charge_card_and_create_event(resource, params)
  end
end
```

With this form:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'signin-fields', placeholder: "Email"
  = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'signin-fields', placeholder: "Password"
  =hidden_field_tag "lesson_name", @lesson.team_name
  =hidden_field_tag "lesson_price", @lesson.price_per_student
  %br
  = f.submit "Log in", class: 'btn btn-ps-sm'

  .shared-links#forgot-password
```

**I have 4 goals once the user clicks `Log in`:**

1. Sign the user in.
2. Extract lesson data from hidden fields, and charge signed-in user's card via API request.
3. Upon successful API response, create a spot for the user in the database.
4. Redirect to or re-render the page with a success or error message.

I have all the logic for steps 2 and 3 all laid out, and obviously sharing all that isn't relevant.  Where I'm stuck is figuring out how to use `super` in the `SessionsController` to log the user in, but delay the redirect until I've performed my actions.  I'm using `after_sign_in_path_for`.

Or the other option would be to completely take out `super` and manually do the whole authentication myself.  But I feel this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your logic inside a block, like so:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do
      my_service = MyService.new
      my_service.charge_card_and_create_event(resource, params)
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't do this, the redirect_to inside devise's create method will be called before your code is executed.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I knew it had to be something simple like this! I shall try it in a couple hours.